# Recursive sql problem

Tags: sql

I have a problem that I would like have solved via a SQL query. This is going to
be used as a PoC (proof of concept).

The problem:

Product offerings are made up of one or many product instances, a product
instance can belong to many product offerings.
This can be realised like this in a table:

```
PO | PI

-----

A | 10

A | 11

A | 12

B | 10

B | 11

C | 13
```

Now I would like to get back the product offer from a set of product instances.
E.g. if we send in 10,11,13 the expected result back is B & C, and if we send in
only 10 then the result should be NULL since no product offering is made up of
only 10. Sending in 10,11,12 would result in A (not A & B since 12 is not a valid product offer in it self).

Prerequisites:
The combination of product instances sent in can only result in one specific
combination of product offerings, so there is only one solution to each query.

Comment: Which database platform?  Oracle?  SQL Server? MySQL?  SQLite? ...

Comment: So querying for 10,11,12 only returns A and not B.  But, if we add D|12 to your product list, then do we then get A, D, *and* B?

Comment: Also, what if we add C|11, then ask for 10,11,13 again?  Do we get B & C again, or do we get neither, since neither 10 or 13 is a PO on its own?

Comment: First question about platform, we can limit it to oracle for this problem.

Comment: Regarding Adams questions, that was what I tried to explain in the prerequisite, that it’s not in scope of the problem as stated, so there will not be a D 12, sorry if I’m not that good at explaining. Does this elaborate things anything?

Comment: @Patrik: Maybe? Let me know if this is correct: Either (1) there will be one PO which exactly contains all requested PIs, or (2) the POs will all be disjoint sets whose union equals the requested PIs. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: Problem: How can "10,11,13" result in "B,C", but "10,11,12" somehow disqualifies "B"? If the "12" disqualifies item "B" because "B" doesn't match "12", then the "13" in the first query should ALSO for the same reason. --- PLEASE explain what you meant by "12 is not a valid product offer in it self."

Comment: @Timothy - It looks like you can only use a single product instance once. So, the combination of (10,11,12) (for A) and (10,11) (for B) is not valid - since you used (10,11) twice. This is what makes it a poor fit for SQL.

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, that's what I'm guessing too.  Actually in my last comment, (1) is just a special case of (2), since if you have only one set you don't have anything else to worry about being disjoint with.

Comment: I think I have a somewhat better formulation for the question: Imagine there is this store that sells certain products. Unfortunately the store does not sell each product alone, but groups them together in "offerings". One product can be in several different offerings, and offerings may contain...

Comment: ...more than one product. Now, when a customer comes, he does not care for this system. He just wants products A, B and C. It is the store's job to pick some offerings for the customer in such a way, that the customer gets EXACTLY what he wants. Not more, not less.

Comment: Assume that the customer does not want several instances of the same product.

Comment: Question:  Is this a classic recursive table such that a Product Offering has a key and a Product Offering can include nested product offerings whereas the bottom level of the tree (the leaf nodes if you will) are the product instances?

Comment: For instance:  Key, ParentKey, OfferingName

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I think I have it.  This meets the constraints you provided.  There might be a way to simplify this further, but it ate my brain a little:

```
select distinct PO 
from POPI x 
where 
  PO not in (
    select PO 
    from POPI 
    where PI not in (10,11,12)
  ) 
  and PI not in (
    select PI 
    from POPI 
    where PO != x.PO 
      and PO not in (
        select PO 
        from POPI 
        where PI not in (10,11,12)
      )
  );
```

This yields only results who fill the given set which are disjoint with all other results, which I **think** is what you were asking for.  For the test examples given:

- Providing 10,11,12 yields A
- Providing 10,11,13 yields B,C

Comment: This one works as expected, nice job! And it verifies my theory that it was possible is SQL-code. I by you a beer if you ever get to Stockholm, Sweden

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Whilst I think mine works fine, Adam's answer is without a doubt more elegant and more efficient - I'll just leave mine here for posterity!

Apologies since I know this has been tagged as an Oracle issue since I started playing. This is some SQL2008 code which I think works for all the stated cases....

```
declare @test table
(
    [PI] int
)
insert @test values (10), (11), (13)

declare @testCount int
select @testCount = COUNT(*) from @test

;with PO_WITH_COUNTS as 
(
        select  PO_FULL.PO, COUNT(PO_FULL.[PI]) PI_Count
        from    ProductOffering PO_FULL
        left
        join    (
                select  PO_QUALIFYING.PO, PO_QUALIFYING.[PI]
                from    ProductOffering PO_QUALIFYING
                where   PO_QUALIFYING.[PI] in (select [PI] from @test)
                ) AS QUALIFYING
                on      QUALIFYING.PO = PO_FULL.PO
                and     QUALIFYING.[PI] = PO_FULL.[PI]
        group by
                PO_FULL.PO
        having  COUNT(PO_FULL.[PI]) = COUNT(QUALIFYING.[PI])
)
select  PO_OUTER.PO
from    PO_WITH_COUNTS PO_OUTER 
cross 
join    PO_WITH_COUNTS PO_INNER
where   PO_OUTER.PI_Count = @testCount
or      PO_OUTER.PO <> PO_INNER.PO
group by
        PO_OUTER.PO, PO_OUTER.PI_Count
having  PO_OUTER.PI_Count = @testCount 
or      PO_OUTER.PI_Count + SUM(PO_INNER.PI_Count) = @testCount
```

Not sure if Oracle has CTEs but could just state the inner query as two derived tables. The cross join in the outer query lets us find combinations of offerings that have all the valid items. I know that this will only work based on the statement in the question that the data is such that there is only 1 valid combination for each requested set, Without that it's even more complicated as counts are not enough to remove combinations that have duplicate products in them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a db in front of me, but off the top of my head you want the list of POs that don't have any PIs not in your input list, ie

```
select distinct po 
from tbl 
where po not in ( select po from tbl where pi not in (10,11,13) )
```

Edit: Here are the example other cases:
When input PI = 10,11,13 the inner select returns A so the outer select returns B, C
When input PI = 10 the inner select returns A,B,C so the outer select returns no rows
When input PI = 10,11,12 the inner select returns C so the outer select returns A,B

Edit: Adam has pointed out that this last case doesn't meet the requirement of only returning A (that'll teach me for rushing), so this isn't yet working code.

Comment: a left join where a column in the joined table is null typically runs faster (but i'm not the one who downvoted you).

Comment: This will also find product offerings that are subsets of the search.

For example, add D | 13 to the table, and D will come up in the results.  I think.  I also don't have a db in front of me.

Comment: This actually seems correct.  From the problem stated, if you add D|13, and 13 is in the PI list, then D should be returned.

Comment: Okay, this is actually not correct for his question, he states 10,11,12 should result in A, not A,B.  But again, this question is worded ambiguously, I've commented above to ask for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Select Distinct PO
   From Table T
   -- Next eliminates POs that contain other PIs
   Where Not Exists 
       (Select * From Table 
        Where PO = T.PO
            And PI Not In (10, 11, 12))
     -- And this eliminates POs that do not contain all the PIs
     And Not Exists 
        (Select Distinct PI From Table  
         Where PI In (10, 11, 12)
           Except 
         Select Distinct PI From Table  
         Where PO = T.PO
```

or, if your database does not implement EXCEPT...

```
   Select Distinct PO
   From Table T
   -- Next predicate eliminates POs that contain other PIs
   Where Not Exists 
       (Select * From Table 
        Where PO = T.PO
            And PI Not In (10, 11, 12))
     -- And this eliminates POs that do not contain ALL the PIs
     And Not Exists 
         (Select Distinct PI From Table A
          Where PI In (10, 11, 12)
             And Not Exists
                 (Select Distinct PI From Table 
                  Where PO = T.PO 
                     And PdI = A.PI))
```

Comment: I ran this against the sample data and got no rows.  I don't understand what you intended the second clause to do.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that a customers asks for a product more than once?

For example: he/she asks an offering for 10,10,11,11,12?

If this is possible than solutions like

select ...
from   ...
where  pi in (10,10,11,11,12)

will not work.

Because 'pi in (10,10,11,11,12)' is the same as 'pi in (10,11,12)'.

A solution for 10,10,11,11,12 is A&B.

Answer (score 0):

well some pseudo code from the top of my head here:

select from table where PI = 10 or pi =11, etc

store the result in a temp table

select distinct PO and count(PI) from temp table.

now for each PO you can get the total available PI offerings. if the number of PIs available  matches the count in the temp table, it means that you have all the PIs for that PO. add all the POs and you ave your result set.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a count of the items in your list, i.e. @list_count.  Figure out which Offerings have Instances that aren't in the list.  Select all Offerings that aren't in *that* list and *do* have Instances in the list:

```
select P0,count(*) c from table where P0 not in (
select P0 from table where P1 not in (@list)
) and P1 in (@list) group by P0
```

I would store that in a temp table and select * records where c = @list_count

Comment: I think that will return cases where @list has more items than a given PO.
eg will return (A, B) for (10, 11, 12), and not (A) as specified. Also you'd want a DISTINCT so you only get one row per PO.

Comment: This is close... but "10,11,12" still returns "A,B", which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If we redefine a bit a problem:

Lets have a customer table with product instances:

```
crete table cust_pi (
pi varchar(5),
customer varchar(5));
```

And a "product_catalogue" table:

```
CREATE TABLE PI_PO_TEST
   ("PO" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),
   "PI" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)
           );
```

Lets fill it with some sample data:

```
insert into CUST_PI (PI, CUSTOMER)
values ('11', '1');
insert into CUST_PI (PI, CUSTOMER)
values ('10', '1');
insert into CUST_PI (PI, CUSTOMER)
values ('12', '1');
insert into CUST_PI (PI, CUSTOMER)
values ('13', '1');
insert into CUST_PI (PI, CUSTOMER)
values ('14', '1');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('A', '10');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('A', '11');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('A', '12');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('A', '13');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('B', '14');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('C', '11');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('C', '12');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('D', '15');
insert into PI_PO_TEST (PO, PI)
values ('D', '14');
```

Then my first shoot solution is like this:

```
select po1 po /* select all product offerings that match the product definition 
                (i.e. have the same number of product instances per offering as 
                in product catalogue */
  from (select po po1, count(c.pi) k1
          from cust_pi c, pi_po_test t
         where c.pi = t.pi
           and customer = 1
         group by po) t1,
       (select po po2, count(*) k2 from pi_po_test group by po) t2
 where k1 = k2
   and po1 = po2
minus /* add those, that are contained within others */
select slave
  from (select po2 master, po1 slave
  /* this query returns, that if you have po "master" slave should be removed from result, 
     as it is contained within*/
          from (select t1.po po1, t2.po po2, count(t1.po) k1
                  from pi_po_test t1, pi_po_test t2
                 where t1.pi = t2.pi
                 group by t1.po, t2.po) t1,
               (select po, count(po) k2 from pi_po_test group by po) t2
         where t1.po2 = t2.po
           and k1 < k2)
 where master in
 /* repeated query from begining. This could be done better :-) */
       (select po1 po
          from (select po po1, count(c.pi) k1
                  from cust_pi c, pi_po_test t
                 where c.pi = t.pi
                   and customer = 1
                 group by po) t1,
               (select po po2, count(*) k2 from pi_po_test group by po) t2
         where k1 = k2
           and po1 = po2)
```

All of that was done on Oracle, so your mileage may vary

Answer (score 0):

I tested this under 4 sets of values and they all returned a correct result. This uses a function that I use in SQL to generate a table from a string of parameters separated by semicolons.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    po varchar(10),
    pii int)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'A', 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 11
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 12
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 11
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 13

DECLARE @value varchar(100)
SET @value = '10;11;12;'
--SET @value = '11;10;'
--SET @value = '13;'
--SET @value = '10;'

SELECT DISTINCT po
FROM @tbl a
INNER JOIN fMultiValParam (@value) p ON
a.pii = p.paramid
WHERE a.po NOT IN (
    SELECT t.po
    FROM @tbl t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM @tbl tt
            INNER JOIN fMultiValParam (@value) p ON
            tt.pii = p.paramid) tt ON
    t.pii = tt.pii
    AND t.po = tt.po
    WHERE tt.po IS NULL)
```

here's the function

```
CREATE    FUNCTION [dbo].[fMultiValParam]
(@Param varchar(5000))
RETURNS @tblParam TABLE (ParamID varchar(40))
AS
BEGIN

IF (@Param IS NULL OR LEN(@Param) < 2)
BEGIN
    RETURN
END

DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @index INT
DECLARE @nextindex INT

SET @len = DATALENGTH(@Param)
SET @index = 0
SET @nextindex = 0

WHILE (@index < @len)
BEGIN
    SET @Nextindex = CHARINDEX(';', @Param, @index)

    INSERT INTO @tblParam
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Param, @index, @nextindex - @index)

    SET @index = @nextindex + 1

END
RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE ( offer, NULL )
FROM products
WHERE instance IN ( @instancelist )
```

Answer (score -1):

IMHO impossible via pure SQL without some stored-procedure code. But... i'm not sure.

**Added:** On the other hand, I'm getting an idea about a recursive query (in MSSQL 2005 there is such a thing, which allows you to join a query with it's own results until there are no more rows returned) which might "gather" the correct answers by cross-joining the results of previous step with all products and then filtering out invalid combinations. You would however get all permutations of valid combinations and it would hardly be efficient. And the idea is pretty vague, so I can't guarantee that it can actually be implemented.

Comment: What he is actually refering to is called a Common Table Expression or CTE

Comment: Yes, CTE. It is a recursive query, isn't it? :)